# Uncaught ReferenceError: XXX is not defined with specific value

Tags: java, jquery, asp.net, eval, linkbutton

I get the following exception when i click on the following link :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: G502 is not defined

---

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lkSelect" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8" OnClientClick='<%# "CallParent(" +Eval("l_room_no").ToString() + " );" %>'><%# Eval("Cell_Data") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Only when :

```
 Eval("l_room_no") = G502
```

---

my script function :

```
 function CallParent(room) {
          //  window.opener.DrawPaths(room);
            // window.close();
            alert(room);
        }
```

Comment: Where is `G502` supposed to be defined? Maybe you want to add quotes or, better, use [`JavaScriptStringEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of `CallParent` should be enclosed between quotes. However, since the data binding expression already uses single and double quotes, you can pass the converted character code to `string.Format`:

```
<asp:LinkButton ... OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("CallParent({0}{1}{0});", (char)39, Eval("l_room_no")) %>' Text='<%# Eval("Cell_Data") %>' />
```

This example assumes that you use C#. The VB.NET equivalent of `(char)39` would be `chr(39)`.

Comment: it works like magic , Could you explain more about `(char)39`

Comment: 39 is the code of the single quote character in ANSI and Unicode tables (http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html). Using the `(char)39` notation allows to specify that character without including it literally in the command, which would cause a conflict with the outer single quotes (`OnClientClick='...'`).

Answer (score 1):

As per current implementation `G502` is treated as variable hence you are getting the error.

```
OnClientClick="<%#string.Format("CallParent('{0}');",Eval("l_room_no")) %>"
```

Comment: `I get parser error :  The server tag is not well formed.`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, Use `OnClientClick="<%#string.Format("CallParent('{0}');",Eval("l_room_no")) %>"`